# How to apply pin to zoom to Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, pinchzoom

Can we apply pinch to zoom for Relative Layout? If we can please share your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there i think you can find useful information about this from here

```
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html
```